# Getting large form to Spring controller

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form whose purpose is to allow a user to create a new entry in a database table. The form is very large, ~50 fields in total. I'm needing a way get all of these values to my controller, though I don't see an easy way. Every solution I've seen is to have a `@RequestParam('field')`, but with around 50 fields that is a little crazy. Maybe if using a `@RequestParam Map<T, T>` is possible?

What I tried at first was to create an AJAX POST call to

`baseapplication.com/add?field1=value1&field2=value2&...&field50=value50`

but then the servlet complained about not finding the `add.jsp` file. This is sort of reasonable because that file does not exist, but I created a controller mapping `@RequestMapping(value="/add")` so I shouldn't actually need that file. I have another method which creates an AJAX GET call to `/search` with some url parameters, and that works fine. There is also no `search.jsp` file.

This problem is hard to explain, I hope I did a halfway decent job. Let's look at some code now, with omissions because dealing with ~50 form fields is very lengthy.

Starting with the JavaScript, which initiates this whole process:

```
ctx = "baseapplication.com"
$('#addNewRecordBtn').on('click', function(){
    var m_insId = document.getElementById('m_insId');
    //This repeats for every field
    var url = ctx + '/add?insuredId=' + m_insId /** + all other fields **/;
    addCase(url);
});

function addCase(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST'
    }).success(function(data){
        alert("Successfully added row");
    }).fail(function(jzXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(jzXHR);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

So the flow of this is as follows: The user clicks on the `addNewRecordBtn` button, which fires the first function. This function grabs the value of every field in the form, then builds a URL with parameters for each of these values. The `addCase()` function is then called, which creates an AJAX POST (not sure what to call this?) to the URL that was just built. This function does not succeed, the error alerts provide zero information, but the server console claims `Failed to find resource /WEB-INF/views/add.jsp`

Now we move into the controller.

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    SpecialClaimsCaseManager caseManager;

    @RequestMapping(value="/add")
    public void addRow(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams) {
        SpecialClaimsCase newCase = new SpecialClaimsCase();

        newCase.setInsuredId(requestParams.get("insuredId"));
        //Repeat this for all parameters

        caseManager.addNewSpecialClaimsCase(newCase);
}
```

The `caseManager.addNewSpecialClaimsCase(newCase)` call just creates a DTO object out of this model object, and then adds that new object to the database via some Hibernate magic. I don't know much about that side, other than it works.

So, I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. I hear there's a way to map a model object to a JSP form using Spring's tag library, but that would require a ton of rewriting as the form is huge. I'm also using Bootstrap to build the interface, and I'm not sure if Bootstrap and Spring's tag library mix well. I can't imagine why not.

I'm not sure if I need to be using AJAX here or not. I went with it because I don't want the page to have to reload or anything. I'm not usually a web developer, so I am sure I am lacking some fundamental knowledge here.

My main question is: given my sitatuation, what is the best way to get this massive form of information into my controller?

Thanks in advance for reading this wall of text and code and for any assistance you can offer!

Comment: Have you considered sending everything as a JSON/XML payload in the POST body ? as opposed to name value pairs?

Comment: Have one single `POJO` for those 50 fields, treat it as a command object, and serialize and post that POJO through an `Ajax` call to Spring `Controller`.

Comment: This might be a silly question but have you tried setting a breakpoint in the addRow method to see if it is getting hit at all?  Also, if you were using jQuery (although I'm not suggesting you have to) you could use the serialize function that it has available so you wouldn't have to grab each individual field.  Check out this link if you don't mind using jQuery.  http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Can you just use a Model Attribute and wrapper all the values you need?  You could put a Map, List, etc in it as well.

Comment: Seriously! You can create a Model (A Java entity whose fields are the same as those in your form)... and Spring MVC will map those for you. You can even do fancy validations.

Comment: @ElGuapo, if you can post that as a proper answer that would be cool. Sounds like a good solution.

Comment: @M7Jacks, yes execution is going into addRow and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a domain class that has all of these needed fields and generate getters and setters and also a constructor. Once you get all these fields/some of these fields POST as json to your controller. The appropriate controller will then call the required service and then the DAO will handle the persistence part.
In short, send the data you need as a JSON object. The json will be made as java object and the operation on the same will be performed.

Here is the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/students/association")
public class StudentDepartmentController {

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@Autowired
private StudentDepartmentService studentDepartmentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/add-department", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<StudentDepartment> createStudentDepartmentAssociation(
        @RequestBody final StudentDepartment studentDepartment) {

    StudentDepartment newStudentDepartment;

    // check if the student exists

    Student student = studentService.getStudentByUuid(studentDepartment
            .getStudentUuid().getUuid());

    if (null == student) {

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No students found!");

    }

    // check the status of student
    if (student.getStatus() == Liveliness.INACTIVE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "cannot create an association with an inactive student! activate student first");
    }

    // check for valid department

    if (null == studentDepartment.getDepartment().getName()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such Department");
    }

    // check if the association already exists

    if (null != findOneAssociationAgainstStudent(student)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "cannot create student department association, as "
                        + student.getUsn()
                        + " already present in another association ( "
                        + studentDepartment.getDepartment().getName()
                        + " )");
    }

    try {

        newStudentDepartment = studentDepartmentService
                .createNewAssociation(studentDepartment);

    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {

        throw new AutomationTransactionException(
                "cannot create student department association, as "
                        + student.getUsn()
                        + " already present in another association ( "
                        + studentDepartment.getDepartment().getName()
                        + " )", ex);

    }

    return new ResponseEntity<StudentDepartment>(newStudentDepartment,
            HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

private StudentDepartment findOneAssociationAgainstStudent(Student student) {

    return studentDepartmentService.findOneAssociation(student);
}

private StudentDepartment findOne(Uuid uuid) {

    String studentDepartmentUuid = uuid.getUuid();

    return findOne(studentDepartmentUuid);

}

private StudentDepartment findOne(String uuid) {

    return studentDepartmentService.findOne(uuid);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete-association", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteStudentDepartmentAssociationByUuid(
        @RequestBody final StudentDepartment studentDepartment) {

    // check if association exists
    StudentDepartment association = findOne(studentDepartment.getUuid());
    if (null == association) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such association found!");
    }

    studentDepartmentService.deleteAssociation(association);

    return new ResponseEntity<String>("success", HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

}`

the `@RequestBody` annotation helps you to make the json object into java object.

with this, you can take the payload as json, and get the java object and send the json back to the UI with `ResponseEntity<Class>` annotation

Comment: I already have the domain class. Do the fields need to be named the same as they are in the JSP form? Does the constructor need to do anything, or will setters work? How should the controller change to access the JSON?

Comment: Sounds like someone is trying to steal my points. But, yes... you'll need to name the properties in the .java file the same as they are listed in your HTML form elements. Also, you'll need to include the Class name of your domain class as part of your endpoint's method signature.

Comment: i will edit my answer so that you can see these in action... i ve done this for a operation i needed to perform on a student and department domain models... please try to map those to your requirements.

Comment: and also, the DI part of the spring will set the required attributes itself. you need not have to explicitly call setters. once you have the object in hand, and want to save the values, do it normally like you would for any other spring managed objects. it would work fine :)

Comment: You probably want to annotate the controller with `@RestController` to implicitly add `@ResponseBody` functionality to the handlers.